# Boolean true value in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to set the hibernate to save -1 instead of 1 as true value for a Boolean field in the database? I need -1 to maintain compatibility with other program made in Delphi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Type(type="com.sample.type.CustomClass")
@Column(name = "TEST_FLAG")
private boolean testFlag;
```

The `@Type` annotation needs a full path to the class that implements the userType interface; this is the factory for producing the target type of the mapped column

CustomClas.java which implements UserType interface provided by hibernate

UserType implementation provides developer to hook the custom logic/implementation and acts as a adapter between relational database and your class property.

You need to write the conversion logic in following methods.

- `nullSafeGet()` : Creates the custom object from the data returned by the result set
- `nullSafeSet()` : Converts custom object into value which needs to be passed to prepared statement

Check the API for detail on the hibernate site.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Integer instead of Boolean?

```
Integer value;
public void setValue(Boolean b) {
    this.value = (b != null ? (b ? -1 : 0) : null);
}
public Boolean getValue() {
    return (this.value != null ? (this.value == -1 ? true : false) : null);
}
```

Comment: A good reason not to do that is that it forces every JPQL query to use `= -1` instead of `= true`.